# how to "hide" my website behind firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

This may sound like a really beginner question, but I got abit confused after reading the documentation.

I understand that there is a

```
signInSuccessUrl: '<url-to-redirect-to-on-success>',
```

inside the `uiConfig`. However, I'm curious where should I put the

```
<div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
```

Does it exist on a separate auth.html file that redirects to my website? (That's how I understand it)

In that case, how do I "hide" my website behind the firebase authentication, does it mean that anyone with the direct link could access the site without the auth? I feel like I'm missing a really important piece here... would gladly appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sign-in button could be on a dedicated page that you choose.  The sensible thing to do would be to immediately redirect to that page if you detect that there is no user signed in.

Firebase Auth won't be very helpful to you if you're trying to protect static content, as your web server will load that up no matter what Firebase Auth knows about the user (unless you arrange for some cookies to be sent that your web server can validate).  Auth is best used to protect dynamic content that requires the user to be signed in with an ID token that can be validated by your backend, or by security rules.